# Initializing array of zeroes in struct causes error

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I am trying to initialize an array inside a struct set to all zeroes.

```
typedef struct month {
    char name[19];
    int yearCounts[10] = { 0 };
    struct month *next;
} MONTH;
```

Compiler doesn't seem to want to let me set yearCounts to values inside the structure. I get the old error:
"expected â:â, â,â, â;â, â}â or â_attribute_â before â=â token"

This seems strange to me, because that exact declaration outside of a structure definition seems to work just fine. If I initialize the array without trying to set its values, it works then, too.

Am I missing something stupid, or am I just not allowed to initialize an array with values inside a structure definition?

I'm compiling using gcc in C89 standard, if that makes a difference.

Comment: You can only initialize objects (not in OOP sense). A typedef defines a type, not an object.

Answer (score 3):

> Am I missing something stupid, or am I just not allowed to initialize
>   an array with values inside a structure definition?

Initializers don't make sense in structure declarations.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify initialization as part of the type definition. You have to wait to initialize until you define an object of that type. With a C89/90 compiler, there's no real way to initialize `yearCounts` without first initializing `name`. In C99 or newer, you can use a designated initializer to initialize only `yearCounts`:

```
MONTH m = { .yearCounts = {0} };
```

Comment: Very understandable for a novice student like me. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps also add, that with that syntax all other fields are initialized to `0`, too, since this is the default.

Answer (score 0):

As `typedef` does the definition of `MONTH` only (and not the actual declaration of an instance of a variables of type `MONTH`) there is nothing to initialse.

```
typedef struct month {
    char name[19];
    int yearCounts[10];
    struct month *next;
} MONTH;

/* declare month as MONTH and initialise it to all zeros. */
MONTH month = {0};
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I had it in mind that, if I were to just declare it in the definition, it would happen automatically whenever I initialized a new one.